# Corona show text from database in newScrollView

Tags: database, sqlite, lua, coronasdk

Im trying to pull some data from SQLite database to the Corona newScollView.

I managed to get data from the database in a tableView, so I thought the code should almost be the same for the newScrollView.

It keeps saying the row is empty, but its not. Any help?

Here is the code:

```
function scene:create( event )

local sceneGroup = self.view   

local function scrollListener( event )

    -- Get reference to the row group
    local row = event.row

    local options_metni = 
    {
        parent = row,
        text = row.params.Metni,
        x = 0,
        y = 0,
        font = native.systemFont,
        fontSize = 16
    }

    local metniObject = display.newText(options_metni)
    metniObject:setTextColor(0)
    metniObject.x = display.contentCenterX
end

---------------------
-- CREATE SCROLLVIEW
---------------------
local scrollView = widget.newScrollView
{
    left = 0,
    top = 0,
    width = display.contentWidth,
    height = display.contentHeight / 2,
    topPadding = 200,
    bottomPadding = 50,
    horiontalScrollDisabled = true,
    verticalScrollDisable = false,
    listener = scrollListener,
}
sceneGroup:insert(scrollView)


---------------------
-- GET DATA FROM DB
---------------------
for row in db:nrows("SELECT baslik FROM dua LIMIT 1") do

if row.data == nil then
    print(" NO DATA FOUND ")
end

    local rowParams = 
    {
        duaID       = row.dua_id,
        Metni       = row.baslik,
    }
end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to insert an object into the scrollView, it doesn't work like the tableView. Try this where the display object is being created and the text is being set from `row.baslik`:

```
for row in db:nrows("SELECT baslik FROM dua LIMIT 1") do
    local text = display.newText( tostring( row.baslik ), 0, 0, native.systemFont, 16 )
    scrollView:insert( text )
end
```